# OpenCV - Best Image Recognition Algorithm

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a "UPS Package Detection" program. The app takes photos of my porch every 1 minute from a Raspberry Pi. I then run a the image through a Feature Matching against a "cube" to detect cubes (packages are cubes, right??)

I decide if a package has been delivered if there are 3 or more observations (see the two images below). I find my algorithm crude, and I know I can do better. Can someone please recommend and advise a better way for me to detect if a package has been delivered.

(I am using Python) Not a package - number of observations very low

[image]

a package - number of observations high

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by observations here? The polished cube is source image ? and destination image is the one with carton boxes ? Try to refine your question.

Comment: The polished cube is source image - yes. The destination image is the one with carton boxes - yes. The "number of observations" is the number of matching features the algorithm finds, as indicated by the lines from the source image to the destination image,

Comment: `I decide if a package has been delivered if there are 3 or more observations` What do you mean by observations  here ?

Comment: run a background subtracter(MOG,GMG) and work on classifying if the detected foreground blob is a parcel.

Comment: @harshkn - Please see the images attached. An "observation" is the number of feature matches that the algorithm finds from the source image to the destination image. In the first example, where there is no package, the number of observations is "1".  In the second example, where there is indeed a package, the number of observations is "11".

Answer (score 0):

No, in your case the packages are not cubes. They are more like a blob.

If you want to detect any package on your porch, not just ups, you can:

A) create a standardized environment for taking the picture (constant illumination, clear background, pattern on the froor, etc). So to say you have to create a package dropping zone that always looks the same to your camera, except when a package is present.
or
B) (the hard way) compare the images over time. I assume, the image we see is taken outside. So there will be different brightness during the day. Shadows. Etc. You can pre process the image accordingly. For example, use a threshold that is calculated as a percentage of the brightest pixel in the image. Then you can compare images over time. If there is a big blob, where was none in the previous images, there might be a package.
or
C) if you only want to detect UPS packages only, you can use OCR or try to match for the UPS logo. This approach will not only detect packages, but also the UPS guy himself :)

However, have fun, it sounds like a really nice home project.

Comment: Thanks :) Great feedback. And, yes, it's a great project!